# Image has a carriage return at the start of the file

Tags: php, image, opencart

I was handed over a site for maintenance/enchancement. The site's platform is running on PHP5, older version of OpenCart (1.5.x).

There is a part where the user is able to download image files using a jquery-based file manager to display files from the /image/ folder.

What happens is that the image file after download fails to load in any image editor/viewer application. When I examined the file with a hex editor, I found out that the start of the JPEG or PNG files starts with a 0x0A (a carriage return). This is the one that is causing the image to fail to be read properly, but how it got there has stumped me since this morning.

There is a testing site on another server with a similar setup. The images can be downloaded and opened correctly. The code should be the same. This part was not touched so I am at a loss on why this happens on Live but not on Testing site.

Has anybody encountered this before, and what is the fix?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean uploaded to the server or downloaded from the server?

Comment: Download from server. If I grab the file directly from the server and examine it, there is no 0x0A at the start of the file. So I am assuming the carriage return is added on download.

Comment: "The code should be the same". First off, find out if it actually *is* the same.

Comment: use winmerge or other tool to compare your js files or do a search for 0x0A on them to findout where/how it is being added.

Comment: Pretty sure it is the same. I have not touched Live. I copied it and deployed it on Testing/Staging. Besides this part has not been touched because the enhancements are not related to this part of Opencart. If I did amend something to the code, this issue should be happening on the latter and not on Live. But it's the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh good lord, there was a carriage return in one of the include files after the ending PHP tag! I should have known this earlier. ***(facepalm)***

Thanks for all the replies.

Regards,
Marky

Comment: I couldn't believe when I find out.  These kind of things are the reason why I don't use PHP more often!!.